# content_main.xml is not generated in android project while using BasicActivity

Tags: android, android-studio, android-activity

I am getting problem during adding BasicActivity.

Yesterday I changed package name of project using refactor. Then after problem starts.

Now when I am creating an activity using basic activity only activity is created. (content is not created)

How to solve this ?

Please help me.

Thanks in advance. 
Adarsh

Comment: You can manually create a new layout resource file and name it content_main.xml and later design the UI. You can then include it in activity_main.xml using <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

Comment: Well I'm not sure why content_main.xml is not generated automatically in your case. Try to create a new project and check whether it is generated automatically.

Comment: in new project its working fine.

Comment: Anything else I should try ?

Comment: I can't really think of anything much that you can try... But try to do a invalidate cache / restart and if this doesn't fix the issue then you may have to import the project again into a latest downloaded copy of AS2.1.2 and check. If it still fails then it is something to within your project which is blocking the default behaviour of AS.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply, I will check it out and will get back to you. Thanks once again.